# HOw to call function inside function from jenkins shared library in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a  x.groovy and a y.groovy file in jenkins shared library under vars.
I need to use the output of a function in x.groovy as an input to a function y.groovy.

x.groovy looks somethins like this :

```
void testM(String msg) {
    int paddingLen = 100
    String bottomLine = '└'.padRight(paddingLen, '─') + '┘\n'
    String topLine = '┌'.padRight(paddingLen, '─') + '┐\n'

    String pM = topLine +
                     "|"+ msg.padRight(200) + "|\n" +
                     bottomLine

    printf(pM)
}
```

```
def display(message) {
   loadColors()
   echo "${GREEN}[INFO] - $message ${NC}"
}
```

In the jenkinsfile I need to use it as  `display.testM("print something here")`.

How shall I do it.Please advice

Comment: I believe the only issue here is incorrect syntax and therefore the normal method and namespace syntax of  `y.display(x.testM("print something here"))` should be correct. However, the other problem here is you stated you want the return of one method as an input for the other, and neither method is returning anything, so that would be another issue.

Answer (score 0):

its not clear how looks your structure but

1. you can call any function from any file of vars/* folder by its name

i.e

```
vars/x.groovy
def firstFunction() {...}
def sesondFunction() {...}
vars/y.groovy 
def firstFunction() {...}
def sesondFunction() {...}
```

will call
x.firstFunction()

or

```
y.firstFunction()
```

by default `y() or x()`it will try to execute `call()` function in your file (if not exist you will see error)

in your case would be best to create one file `vars/DisplayMessage.groovy`

with

```
String formatMessage(String msg) {
  int paddingLen = 100
  String bottomLine = '└'.padRight(paddingLen, '─') + '┘\n'
  String topLine = '┌'.padRight(paddingLen, '─') + '┐\n'

  String pM = topLine +
    "|"+ msg.padRight(200) + "|\n" +
    bottomLine

  return pM
}

def call(String message) {
  String formatedMessage = x.formatMessage(message)

  loadColors()
  echo "${GREEN}[INFO] - ${formatedMessage} ${NC}"
}
```

and use it in pipeline as `DisplayMessage("your message")`

if not you can always use `y.display(x.testM("print something here"))` from comment